# Why is Firefox ignoring the source element in a picture?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In my code I have 2 images: the first is for all devices except mobiles and the second is for mobiles. Everything works as it should but not in Firefox: Firefox always takes the second one.

```html
<picture class="page__hero">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/300/ff0000" 
    media="(min-width: 769px)" width="718" height="180">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" 
    width="269" height="67" alt="Good alt text">
</picture>
```

I tried not to set `width` and `height` in both `<source>` and `<img>` elements, it works as expected then. But as far as I know we should set both attributes to prevent layout shifts.

What am I doing wrong?
How I should control `width` and `height` then? In CSS?

Comment: I tested the snippet I created above in Firefox. It shows the red image for larger screens.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your snippet, I see red square in Firefox, but the size is not correct , the width is taken from ```<img>```. I tried to change the width of the viewport, the color changes but not the width, the width stays the same.